# How can oddly shaped lists be zipped in Elm?

Tags: elm

I have two data structures I would like to combine in my Elm program. Their types are `List (a, List b)` and `List c`. This is the simplest way to store the data in the model, but I would like to write a function to transform it to a view model before displaying it.

```
type alias Model1 a b = List (a, List b)
type alias Model2 c = List c

type alias ViewModel a b c = List (a, List (b, c))

toViewModel : Model1 -> Model2 -> ViewModel
toViewModel model1 model2 =
  ???
```

The `toViewModel` function should zip the sub-lists in model 1 with the elements of model 2. Assume the size of model2 is the same as the sum of the sizes of the sub-lists in model 1.

For example, if model1 has length 2 and the two elements' sublists have lengths 3 and 4, assume model 2 will have length 7. Model 1's first element's sublist should be zipped with the first 3 elements of model 2, and model 1's second element's sublist should be zipped with the next 4 elements of model 2.

Here's a diagram of the previous example:

[image: Diagram of example drawn on paper]

How can the `toViewModel` function be constructed?

Answer (score 3):

Elm doesn't have a built-in `zip` function but it's easy to define it in terms of `List.map2`:

```elm
zip : List a -> List b -> List (a, b)
zip = List.map2 (,)
```

You can't use that on the disjointed list by itself, but you can use it to zip up the sub-lists in Model1 with the first `n` items from Model2. To get the list of things that need to be zipped up, you'll just need to use `List.take` for the zipping portion, and `List.drop` to get the remaining items from Model2 that need to be zipped up with the next Model1 entity. This can be done using something like the following functionn.

```elm
toViewModel : Model1 a b -> Model2 c -> ViewModel a b c
toViewModel m1 m2 =
  case m1 of
    [] ->
      []

    ((m1ID, m1List)::rest) ->
      let
        len = List.length m1List
        init' = List.take len m2
        tail' = List.drop len m2
      in
        (m1ID, zip m1List init') :: toViewModel rest tail'
```

Notice that using `zip` is going to stop at whichever list ends first, so if you have lists of uneven length, items are going to get dropped.

**Edit** - *Here's an additional way of doing this where the explicit recursion is isolated in a way that the main functionality can be achieved through mapping*

Another way to solve this would be to first group Model2 into a list of lists, where each item contains an appropriate number of elements for the equivalent Model1 entry.

For this I'll define a function `takes` which splits up a list into a number of smaller lists, the sizes of these lists being passed in as the first parameter.

```elm
takes : List Int -> List a -> List (List a)
takes counts list =
  case counts of
    [] -> []
    (x::xs) -> List.take x list :: takes xs (List.drop x list)
```

Now you can use the `takes` function to group the Model2 list, allowing you to map it against the Model1 input so you can zip the internal lists.

```elm
toViewModel : Model1 a b -> Model2 c -> ViewModel a b c
toViewModel model1 model2 =
  let
    m2Grouped = takes (List.map (List.length << snd) model1) model2
    mapper (m1ID, m1List) m2List = (m1ID, zip m1List m2List)
  in
    List.map2 mapper model1 m2Grouped
```

Comment: I've fixed the type aliases. In the actual code I'm writing they are concrete types so I made the mistake of omitting them when I generalized my code for example purposes.

Comment: I fixed a logic error in my answer and removed the now-obsolete type alias recommendation

Comment: Is this an accurate, generalized summary of your answer? "To combine oddly shaped lists, use pattern matching and recursion, as `zip = List.map2 (,)` is probably not flexible enough."

Comment: Pattern matching and recursion are so central to Elm you might as well say "Use a function which fits yours needs." In a strongly typed language like Elm, you'll often hear the phrase, "Let the types guide you." Since the types don't fit into the `zip` function, you have to define your own function to zip things up.

Comment: They're central, but they're low level. I was expecting the answer to my question would be some kind of fold statement. Erik Meijer has said "Recursion is the GOTO of functional programming," and I take that to mean your first instinct should be to look for a higher abstraction before using it. That's what I was trying to address in my summary.

Comment: You certainly could use a fold, but then you're going to have to include the tail end of the unused Model2 list in your accumulator since it changes each pass; you're kind of crudely tracking state at that point. That route, IMO, seems a little more convoluted, whereas my recursive example feels more elegant and simpler to comprehend. As for Eric's comment, he [clarifies his comment as not repeating yourself](https://twitter.com/headinthebox/status/409786151830945792) rather than as an attack on recursion

Comment: I agree the recursive model is more elegant and simple here, but it is usually not. Usually a HO function is better; I bet your code has more `map` statements than recursive ones. I think the root of why your answer is good is that it deliberately _does_ use recursion since this is an occasion where it's appropriate, and I am trying to emphasize that. Even more generally, your answer could be summarized as "use a lower abstraction level."

Comment: I've updated my answer with another solution which isolates the explicit recursion and allows a subjectively simpler `toViewModel` function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly simplier take on the task:

1. Use [List.concatMap](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/3.0.0/List#concatMap) to create a flat `List (a, b)` from `Model1`
2. Merge it with `Model2`, to get `List (a, b, c)` with data from both lists
3. Group the list by `a` to get final `List (a, List (b, c))` with [List.filterMap](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/3.0.0/List#filterMap)

I've had to mock some data to run the tests here.

Please consider the following example:

```
import Graphics.Element exposing (show) 


-- List (a, List b)
type alias Model1 = List (String, List Int)


-- List c
type alias Model2 = List Bool


-- List (a, List (b, c))
type alias ViewModel = List (String, List (Int, Bool))


toViewModel : Model1 -> Model2 -> ViewModel
toViewModel model1 model2 =
  let
    -- Map merge both lists and map values to the grouping key.
    mappedList =
      model1
      |> List.concatMap (\(groupBy, list) -> List.map (\el -> (groupBy, el)) list)
      |> List.map2 (\val2 (groupBy, val1) -> (groupBy, (val1, val2))) model2

    -- Extract a list for for specified grouping key.
    getListByKey search =
      List.filterMap
        (\(key, val) -> if key == search then Just val else Nothing)
        mappedList

  in
    List.map (\(search,_) -> (search, getListByKey search)) model1


initModel1 : Model1
initModel1 =
  [ ("foo", [ 1, 2, 3 ])
  , ("bar", [ 4, 5, 6, 7])
  ]


initModel2 : Model2
initModel2 =
  [ True
  , False
  , True
  , False
  , True
  , False
  , True
  ]

main =
  toViewModel initModel1 initModel2
  |> show
```